# How to run the following command in Ubuntu and which path it is referring to?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

Following is my set of script that I need to run but I am not sure about the path it is referring to ? and should I put the whole script in .sh file and then run, or something else to execute the node project ?

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
redis-server --save "" &
sleep 1
redis-cli flushall
cd ~/repos/class-prj/class-prj
npm run app.js
```

Comment: You can copy those lines into any file (extension is irrelevant) and then make it executable for your user with `chmod u+x /PATH/TO/SCRIPT`. After that, execute it with `/PATH/TO/SCRIPT`, or, if you're in the same directory as the script, `./SCRIPT`. And I don't understand your question about the path?

Comment: @ByteCommander I am referring to the path `cd ~/repos/class-prj/class-prj`  btw seems its working ..but I dont know why its saying `line 2: redis-server: command not found`  though its running at `tcsolvr@my-pc:~/redis-3.0.5$ src/redis-server`

Comment: Same in the script: if you run an executable in the current directory, use `./EXECUTABLE`, or the full `/PATH/TO/EXECUTABLE`. So replace line 2 with `~/redis-3.0.5/src/redis-server --save "" &` and it should work. You also should not use `cd` in scripts, because then you will be in a different directory after running the script than before. You can e.g. use `pushd` instead of `cd` to enter a directory and `popd` to return to the directory you were in before the last call to `pushd`.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks for the valuable info ..and helping me out with the proper explanation ..please add to the answer and I will upvote & accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your script to contain the full path to your `redis-server` executable and you should avoid `cd` or at least restore the current working directory afterwards (e.g. using `pushd` and `popd`):

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
~/redis-3.0.5/src/redis-server --save "" &
sleep 1
redis-cli flushall
pushd ~/repos/class-prj/class-prj
npm run app.js
popd
```

You can save this script in a file with any name, the file extension is irrelevant and can also be omitted. What is important is to make it executable for your user instead:

```
chmod u+x /PATH/TO/SCRIPT
```

Now you may run the script by simply entering its full absolute path or its relative path. That means you have to write `./SCRIPT` as relative path if it's in the current directory!

Comment: sorry I am unable to upvote as dont have enough reputation..will upvote in future for sure

Comment: No problem. To know I have saved someone's day is the biggest reward - although some imaginary internet points are also quite nice! ;-D